Access to the searched word in Filters through the Table class
Friends, I have a table (django-tables2) and a search filter called 'comment'. (django-filters)
I want to access the searched word inside the Table class.
For example, inside the qs() event or somewhere else, I pass it to the request, so that I can access it on the other side in the Table class.
class CommentsView(LoginRequiredMixin, SingleTableMixin, FilterView):
    model = Comments
    queryset = Comments.objects.all().order_by('-id')
    table_class = CommentTable
    filterset_class = CommentFilter

Filter :
class CommentFilter(FilterSet):

    class Meta:
        model = Comments
        fields = ['comment']

    @property
    def qs(self):
        parent = super().qs

        # here I want to pass it
        search_key=self.data.get('comment')

        return parent

The table class :
class CommentTable(tables.Table):   
    def render_comment(self, record):
        # access here like self.request.GET.get('search_key')
        return record.comment


So highlighting the searched words?

@willeM_VanOnsem Almost yes, this is part of the goal.

what is the "almost" exactly what is the difference between what you want to achieve?

The other part of the goal is not related to this topic, that is to highlight the word in a state where a part of the text before and after it, is displayed in the comment.

So what do you use as view, a TableView, how do you let the FilterSet and CommentTable work together?

@willeM_VanOnsem new update !

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

After searching up and down and of course getting help from a friend, I found an answer and I will put it here so that if someone needs it in the future, it can be used :
First: In the filter class, I entered search_key as a property
 def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(SearchCommentFilter, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.search_key = self.data.get('comment', '')

After that I read it and send it to table class in the view
 def get_table(self, **kwargs):
    table = super().get_table(**kwargs)
    filterset = self.get_filterset(self.filterset_class)
    search_key = getattr(filterset, 'search_key', None)
    table.search_key = search_key
    return table

Finally, I used it in the table class
 def render_comment(self, record):
    search_key = getattr(self, 'search_key', None)
    return record.comment.replace(search_key, f"<mark>{search_key}</mark>")

